# Cannot get value when accessing Hash via CSV in ERB

Tags: ruby

I currently have this hash,

```
{ "meal"         => "Bomb mi ",
  "meal_type "   => "Bombwiches",
  "times_served" => "8AM to 3PM",
  "days_served"  => "Tuesday - Sunday",
  "notes"        => "Hoisin glazed shredded pork or tofu, fresh jalapenos, house-made pickled daikon & carrots, pickles, fresh cilantro, sriracha and a fried egg. ",
  "price"        => "13.25" }
```

that I'm able to access in irb via `@menu_items[i]`

The data is coming from a csv that i'm loading using Sinatra

```
get "/menu" do
  data_file = 'rabbit-sinatra.csv'
  @menu_items = []
  CSV.foreach(data_file, headers: true, :encoding => 'utf-8') do |row|
    @menu_items << row.to_hash
  end
  erb :menu
end
```

I'm then looping through this and pulling out any and all necessary values in erb.

```
<% for i in 0..70 do %>
          <% if @menu_items[i]["meal_type"] == "Bombwiches" %>
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="foo"> <%= @menu_items[i]["meal"]%> </div>
                <div class="times_served"> <%= @menu_items[i]["times_served"]%> </div>
                <div class="days_served"> <%= @menu_items[i]["days_served"]%> </div>
                <div class="notes"> <%= @menu_items[i]["notes"]%> </div>
                <div class="price"> <%= @menu_items[i]["price"]%> </div>
            </div>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
```

Although `@menu_items[i]["notes"]` and all other hash parsing commands work, for some reason the initial "meal" value is not being picked up when i run

```
@menu_items[i]["meal"]
```

Instead of returning the value for meal `"meal" => "Bomb mi "` it returns nothing.

Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Maybe lose the [i]? The index to the hash entry is "meal", so the extra [i] serves no purpose.

Comment: @PeterCamilleri please see updated question.

Comment: What does `@menu_items[i].keys.include?("meal")` return?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 it returns false, which is interesting.....strange.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce.

```
i = 1
@menu_items[i] = 
    { "meal"         => "Bomb mi ",
      "meal_type "   => "Bombwiches",
      "times_served" => "8AM to 3PM",
      "days_served"  => "Tuesday - Sunday",
      "notes"        => "Hoisin glazed shredded pork or tofu, fresh jalapenos, house-made pickled daikon & carrots, pickles, fresh cilantro, sriracha and a fried egg. ",
      "price"        => "13.25" }

puts @menu_items[i]["price"] #=> "13.25"
puts @menu_items[i]["meal"] #=> "Bomb mi "
```

Clearly it doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: Thanks for answering, however i'm not sure if I understand your response. You say you can not reproduce that reproduce using `menu_items[i]["menu"] #=> "Bomb mi "` which is not an option in the hash. Can you explain?